# A specific background image won't show up under an account on my mac

Tags: html, css, macos, osx-snow-leopard

This is the strangest issue I have ever encountered. I have a Mac running 10.6, and on every browser one specific background image does not show up. Furthermore it doesn't work in VMWare Fusion either. I decided to create a test profile to see what would happen, I open up the web page and voila, the image appears. Now if I were having the issue on one browser I would just dump the cache (have already done this on every browser) and try again. Obviously that is not the case here. This has got to be a serious one off, but hopefully someone has seen it before.

Comment: what info do you need? Other background images work fine. A specific one doesn't no matter what browser. Only on this computer. Every other computer works fine.

Comment: Where is the programming part of your question? If you have one, please provide it. If not, your question belongs on superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Odd. Possible causes:

- Hard disk failure / disk full / file system corrupt (unlikely)
- This user has a plugin installed like AdBlock (unlikely - would be browser specific but maybe that user has installed it for all the browsers you tried)
- The user uses a proxy which blocks the image (like [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/)). Are proxy settings on Mac global for all applications?
- The user has installed an anti-virus or something which filters web connections.